# How to create an Android ListView with section header xamarin android? I got 17 errors

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In this example we will show how to create a ListView with section header. This involves following steps

Create two custom layout for your List header and List row
Create your custom adapter for ListView
Instantiate ListView in your activity

I had got 17 errors. I want to create listview with section header xamarin android.
http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android

I convert from java to C#

```html
>  - `public class CustomAdapter:BaseAdapter`->does not implement abstract member `android.widget.baseAdapter.getitem(int)`
>  - `Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ()`-> An object reference is requered to access non-static member .....
>  - `return mData.GetRange(position)`;-> no overload for method 'getrange'take 1 arguments
>  - `convertView = mInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.textViewHeaderItems, false)`;-> the
> best overloaded method match for ..... has some invalid arguments
>  - `convertView.SetTag(holder);`-> no overload for method ... tkae 2 arguments
>  - `holder.textView.SetText(mData.get(position))`; type system.collection.generic.list<string> does not contain a defintion
> for 'get'and no extension method 'get'of type
> `system.Colleciton.Generic.List<string>` could be found. Are you
> missing an assembly
```

```html
public class CustomAdapter:BaseAdapter
  {
   private  const int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
   private  const int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

   private List<String> mData = new List<String>();
   private TreeSet sectionHeader = new TreeSet();

   private LayoutInflater mInflater;

   public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
     .GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
   }

   public void addItem(String item) {
    mData.Add(item);
    Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();
   }

   public void addSectionHeaderItem(String item) {
    mData.Add(item);
    sectionHeader.Add(mData.Count - 1);
    Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();
   }

  
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return sectionHeader.Contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
   }

 
   public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
   }

 
   public int getCount() {
    return mData.Count;
   }

  
   public String getItem(int position) {
    return mData.GetRange(position);
   }

  
   public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
   }

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
     holder = new ViewHolder();
     switch (rowType) {
     case TYPE_ITEM:
      convertView = mInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.textViewHeaderItems, false);
      holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textviewHeaderItems);
      break;
     case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
      convertView = mInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.textViewItemsSeparator, false);
      holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textviewItemsSeparator);
      break;
     }
     convertView.SetTag(holder);
    } else {
     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.GetTag();
    }
    holder.textView.SetText(mData.get(position));

    return convertView;
   }

   public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "Search" function on Xamarin's Dev site for questions like these:

- https://developer.xamarin.com

Note: Google or Bing is also your best friend for questions like these.

`Android.Content.Context.LayoutInflaterService`

> Use with Context.GetSystemService(String) to retrieve a LayoutInflater for inflating layout resources in this context.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Content.Context.LayoutInflaterService/

`Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged`

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged/

`Java.Util.TreeSet`

> TreeSet is an implementation of SortedSet.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.Util.TreeSet/

Comment: I us the "search" but there are much information. I don't understand

Comment: cann't use treeset<>

Comment: Updated my post. please can you check it